# Выполнить php скрипт в файле из подключенного?

Tags: php

Добрый день
как осуществить выполнение скрипта в самом файле, если скрипт находиться в прикрепленном?
т.е.
есть шаблон `index.html` для страниц в разных каталогов внутри сайта:

```
<?php
   include ("../../header.html");
?>
содержимое файла
<?php
   include ("../../footer.html");
?>
```

сейчас возникла потребность вывести имя соответствующего каталога для каждой страницы index.html

Скрипт:

```
<?php
    echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```

если я этот скрипт добавляю в `footer.html` то на страницах появляется "корень сайт" так как файл `footer.html` находиться в корне!

Как выполнить скрипт на страницах `index.html` при условии, что не вручную в каждый файл добавлять?

Comment: @vik-smit, вы бы для начала заменили расширения Ваших темплейтов (`header.html`, `footer.html`,...) на `.php`. Конечно, можно переопределить handler (добавить дполнительные расширения) в настройках сервера, чтобы он на html "натравливал" интерпретатор, но так никто не делает.

Comment: @vik-smit, и вообще, придерживаетесь BEST-практик. [Почитайте мое краткое описание MVC подхода](http://hashcode.ru/questions/400355#400410) (после UPDATE #2).